# Light green grass patches

Tags: grass

I am trying to figure out what these light patches of grass in my lawn are and how to get rid of them?  And prevent them? First two picture were taken last summer. The close up picture of the grass where taken today. They seem to be getting larger and spreading. I notice them the most in the areas that get a lot of shade? Is it Poa Trivialis? Over watering the issue? We also have alot of deer in our yard. Not sure if deer urine will do this?

I started pulling it up and will reseed it this spring. It comes up like a carpet because the root are really shallow.

enter image description here [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the roots growing underground to spread (rhizomes) or on top of the soil (stolons)?  It looks like it could be nibbleweed, a cousin of bent grass.   Also, where are you located?

Comment: looks like on top of the soil.  I am in Massachusetts.

Comment: Nibbleweed or bentgrass should have died out. Identification is the first step. Try to find a tool online.